# Images of page not rendered to pdf using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I have few images in my web page , i am trying to convert a div element which has images to pdf as :

```
    var element = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    doc.addHTML(element, function () {
        doc.save('testdoc.pdf');
    });
```

The pdf doesn't show images in `testdoc.pdf` , should i need to add any more attributes ?

A Quick Q :

- Is it possible to convert full page to image (with all images and styles of web page) similar to pdf by jsPDF with other libraries ?

If so please guide me with some links , any help is much appreciated thanks .

Comment: There used to be [*html2canvas*](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), yet I am not aware of the current status on it.

Comment: @JavaScript I would look in to that :)

Answer (score 0):

After a little surfing and workaround :

1. Images should be in **.JPG**
2. If you are trying any images from say **online** or from **AWS** add this below conf :

```js
var opt = {
      image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 }, // as per req

      html2canvas: { dpi: 300,
                    letterRendering: true,
                    useCORS: true },
    };
```

Comment: hi, are u sure it will work,  i tried this with webp images . but it didn't work for me. here is my code . ```var pdfConf = {
        pagesplit: true,
        background: "#fff",
        image: { type: "webp", quality: 0.98 }, // as per req
        html2canvas: { dpi: 300, letterRendering: true, useCORS: true },
      };
      var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", [
        invoiceSection.height() + 100,
        invoiceSection.width(),
      ]);
      pdf.addHTML(invoiceSection, pdfConf, function () {
        pdf.save(`${invoiceName}.pdf`);
      });```

Comment: I'm not sure of "webp" ... may you can check their GH issues if not you can create an issue ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74807762/jspdf-jspdf-not-rendering-aws-image-into-pdf . I have also created an issue in stackoverflow also

Comment: I would suggest to log the issue in GitHub on their library code ...

Comment: ya there is an issue alredy opened in github https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3376 but is there any thing to work around.

Comment: Sorry no idea ... That was way back i used it ...