# jsPDF is not rendering img with url on the first page

Tags: jspdf

I have a html div with some img src url inside it. The img part looks like this:

```
<div><img src="https://www.example.com//cover.png"></div>
```

I'm using jsPDF to generate the pdf:

```
new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true).html(
      document.getElementById('printDiv'),
      {
        filename: 'print.pdf',
        image: { quality: 10, type: 'png' },
        html2canvas: {
          /*
          scale: 2,
          */
        },
        callback: function (doc) {
          doc.save();
        },
      }
```

However, it looks like the img only on the first page is not be showing. I guess img loading takes some time and happened after first page render done, I detected it by using `html2canvas scale 2` so that the image pushed into 2nd page.

[image: image in 1st page not showing]

[image: image got pushed into 2nd page]

How can I fix the code to let the image on the first page being generated before pdf is rendered?

Comment: I ended up with this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854132/convert-html-page-to-pdf-in-angular-using-jspdf-and-html2canvas?rq=1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64691791/19554161

Answer (score 0):

Wait with the jsPDF call until the image has loaded.